# Linking to static html pages from wordpress blog

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a static site with a few pages and an installation of Wordpress. I uploaded wordpress to the server and I am able to access it from any of the static pages using the link        href="blog\". The static html pages are stored in the main directory of the server which is also where the blog is stored. the directory looks like this:

```
public_html/   //Server directory
-index.html
-contact.html
-about.html
-blog/         //Folder with blog installation
--wp-content/
---themes/
----theme_name/ 
-----file_with_links.php
```

Im trying to put links in the php file "file_with_links.php" that will link back to the static html pages which are a few directories up from it. I tried to do use  ../../../../../page.html with no luck. Is there an easy way to do this? any help would be appreciated.

-Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice is using a full URI (`http://YourSiteHere.com/YourFileHere.html`).

To achieve this, use this code in your `file_with_links.php` file:

```
$root_toot = "http://YourSiteHere.com";

$to_contact = '<a href="' . $root_toot . '/contact.html">Contact</a>';
$to_about = '<a href="' . $root_toot . '/about.html">About</a>';
```

Etc.